# Can an extension override font behavior?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use the [Operator Mono](http://www.typography.com/blog/introducing-operator) font. In VS Code italics, and font behavior are defined by the themes. Here's an example of [italic comments](https://github.com/andischerer/vscode-theme-atom-one-dark/blob/master/themes/AtomOneDark.tmTheme#L69) in an Atom One Dark theme.

My question is: Is there a way to override this behavior, maybe through an extension? I would like to make an extension that lets you override theme font behavior. So that themes, such as the default VS Code one, could be italicized, bolded, etc... as you wish.

Is this something that Extensions can handle in any way?

If this question is too deep into the guts of how the editor works I'll make an issue in the repository, but it did say that if you have a question you should ask here.

Cheers.